# ModuleNotFoundError in flask app while importing 'app' folder

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting a **ModuleNotFoundError** while running my flask app with this dir structure:

```
project
     | app
          | __init__.py
          | urls.py
          | views.py
     | __main__.py
```

In the project dir, while running `python3 .`, I'm getting a

```
File "./app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import urls
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urls'
```

The content of `__init__.py` is

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
import flask_cors
import urls
from views import flask_app

log = logging.getLogger("werkzeug")
log.disabled = True
flask_cors.CORS(flask_app)

def run(host, port):
    flask_app.run(host=host, port=port)
```

The code is a little big so [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TqqB-TpDZbXLXlADzk9PpCUibVkfrkTx/view?usp=sharing) is the link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import other files in the same directory in a `__init__.py` file, you need to use relative import syntax:

```
from . import urls
```

This way Python will look for `urls.py` alongside your `__init__.py`, instead of searching in `sys.path`.

Comment: Is there a way to import an object from the module, ie `from ./views import flask_app`, which ofc is not a correct statement?

Comment: @HackaTunes `from .view import something` should do.

Comment: **ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**

Comment: @HackaTunes Hmmm, now just remove the dot (`from view`)

Comment: Oooookkkkkkkkkk I made a typo its all good now :D

Comment: Hi @iBug, can you help me with this one? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67748683/how-do-i-return-a-value-from-a-row-by-querying-a-sqlite3-database